# API Gateway Access Log using Cloudformation

Tags: aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, access-log

I need to enable Custom Access Logging in API Gateway. The cloudformation is written in yaml. But for the format of the custom logs it is in json, xml such formats but nothing is mentioned how to set format of access log in yaml. Does anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

From the [CloudFormation user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-stage-accesslogsetting.html), the `Format` attribute requires your input to be `String`.

```
  DestinationArn: String
  Format: String
```

For example:

```
  DestinationArn: !Sub ${ApiAccessLogGroup.Arn}
  Format: "{ 'requestId':'$context.requestId', 'ip': '$context.identity.sourceIp', 'caller':'$context.identity.caller', 'user':'$context.identity.user','requestTime':'$context.requestTime', 'xrayTraceId':'$context.xrayTraceId', 'wafResponseCode':'$context.wafResponseCode', 'httpMethod':'$context.httpMethod','resourcePath':'$context.resourcePath', 'status':'$context.status','protocol':'$context.protocol', 'responseLength':'$context.responseLength' }"
```

To simplify your `String` or make it looks better, please use `!Sub` as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070155/in-cloudformation-yaml-use-a-ref-in-a-multiline-string-use-fnsub).